# Handlebars template being rendered as raw html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to just get a simple page running with node and handlebars, but the page doesn't render correctly. When I go to http://localhost:8080/ I just get raw HTML text in the browser. Here's my code:

**main.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', 8080);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

**home.handlebars**

```
<h1>The Home Page</h1>
```

**main.handlebars**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

I'm running this in NetBeans but even if I try doing it through the command line, the result is the same.

EDIT: Even weirder, it renders fine in Firefox, but not in IE or Chrome.

EDIT2: More weirdness. If I change the port to something else, Firefox will stop rendering correctly. Firefox only renders correctly when its port 8080.

EDIT3: Here's an image of what I'm seeing:
[image]

EDIT4: I made a change to main.handlebars, saved it, tested it, undid the change and saved it again (so it was back to its original state), and now Firefox won't render either.

EDIT5: It seems to be working now and I have *absolutely no idea why*. If anyone wants to take a closer look, I have the files saved here: https://github.com/tliss/ExerciseApp

Comment: Did you try removing this line: `res.type('text/plain');` ?

Comment: Gave it a shot but it had no effect.

Comment: Use `var server = http.createServer(app);server.listen(8080, function () {});` instead (_and I think it's __Firefox__ not __FireFox__ as I saw in Mozilla.org & any other places_)

Comment: Tried it but there is still no change in output.

Comment: Triple curlies around `{{{body}}}` rather than double?  I believe that escapes whatever's inside, although it doesn't explain why it would escape the whole of the document, including `<head>` and s on.

Comment: Have you tried to set the type to 'test/html' instead?

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem with express handlebars template, try this

- triple curly braces instead of double
- clear cache
- remove res.type()
- use these two lines for setting view engine

`app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `res.type('text/plain');` and restart the server and clear browser cache (on Chrome you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).